# Teardown Errors when testing with Jest, Supertest, MongoDB, and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs, supertest

I'm testing my Express routes with Jest and Supertest. While setting up the app, I'm also connecting to MongoDB and adding the MongoClient to `app.locals`.

I'm getting an error which doesn't happen when I comment out my call to MongoClient.

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at BufferList.Readable (server/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:179:22)
      at BufferList.Duplex (server/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
      at new BufferList (server/node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
      at new MessageStream (server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
      at new Connection (server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:54:28)
/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:111
  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex;
                        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
    at new ReadableState (/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:111:25)
    at BufferList.Readable (/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:183:25)
    at BufferList.Duplex (/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
    at new BufferList (/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
    at new MessageStream (/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
    at new Connection (/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:54:28)
    at /Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:36:29
    at callback (/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
    at TLSSocket.connectHandler (/Users/zackchan/Documents/dev/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:325:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
```

When I comment out my MongoClient call, I get this Jest warning:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Here's my test script and app module

**app.js**

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const express = require('express');
const rateLimiter = require('express-rate-limit');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 443;
const limit = rateLimiter({ window: 15 * 60 * 1000, max: 100 });

var httpsOptions;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    const rootCA = require('ssl-root-cas').create().addFile(path.join(__dirname, './cert/CA.pem'));
    https.globalAgent.options.ca = rootCA;
    httpsOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './cert/localhost.key')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './cert/localhost.crt'))
    };
}

MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, mongoClient) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    app.locals.mongoClient = mongoClient;
});

app.use(limit);
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({path: '/'});
});

const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(port);

module.exports = app;
```

**test.js**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
process.env = dotenv.config({path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env')}).parsed;

const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');


describe('GET /', () => {
    it('responds with path of /', (done) => {
        // app.locals is empty here
        request(app).get('/').expect(JSON.stringify({path: '/'}), done);
    });
});
```

I've tried closing the connection to MongoDB after the test case using `app.locals.mongoClient.close()` but `mongoClient` is undefined here. I've also tried wrapping the `MongoClient.connect()` call in an async function then calling it but that doesn't help either.

Anyone have thoughts on what I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by:

1. Following instructions from [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb). You can still access the MongoDB connection through `req.app.locals` if you assign it to `app.locals` in the `test.js` file.
2. Wrapped my `MongoClient.connect()` call in `app.js`:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    MongoClient.connect(...)
}
```